# Why mutate() doesn't work in SWR with useSWRInfinite?

Tags: next.js, swr

I am loading elements by clicking on the button on next js via SWRInfinite. Everything works and the data is loaded. But when I go to another page and return to the page with SWRInfinite, all the data that was loaded earlier is still displayed on the page.

[[I try to reset them by executing mutate(); in useEffect, but it doesn't help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejOcJ.jpg)

```
    const { data, mutate, size, setSize, isValidating, isLoading } =
    useSWRInfinite(
      (index) =>
        `/api/sites-lists?sort[0]=order%3Aasc&populate=logo&pagination[page]=${
          index + 1
        }&pagination[pageSize]=${pageSize}&populate=slides`,
      fetcher,
      {
        fallbackData: siteList, // Передача начальных данных
      }
    );

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.